# Changing a canvas size without rescaling image using Wand and ImageMagick

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I'd like to make my images square without affecting their aspect ratio, so I need to pad out the canvas size for example to make the height as large as the width and then I can rescale the image. I don't see a smart way of doing this. I had a look in the docs, but didn't see anything: http://docs.wand-py.org/

It seems resizes or crop's wont do this. I tried:

```
img.crop(0, 0, width=dim, height=dim)
```

I appreciate that this routine might depend on the background, but if I assume for simplicity at the moment that the images all have a white background (Later I may want to sample and add the type of background).

Comment: Implementing this is one of my favourite questions to ask candidates at interview.

Comment: I think the answer has the word `extent` in it...

Comment: @DanielRoseman, please elaborate

Answer (score 3):

If you start off at the commandline with an image like this:

```
convert -size 200x120 xc:red a.png
```

[image]

And resize it to 100x100, like this:

```
convert a.png -resize 100x100 b.png
```

you will get an image that is 100x60 because ImageMagick wants to preserve the apect ratio. If you want that image to be padded to a square, you will need to  use `-extent` like this (I have made the background yellow so you can see it):

```
convert a.png -resize 100x100 -background yellow -gravity center -extent 100x100 b.png
```

[image]

I don't see any mention of the word `-extent` in the Python Wand documents, so I assume it is not present. As such, I thiink you will probably need to make a new, second, square image and composite your resized image onto it. Unless anyone else knows better...

Comment: Thanks Mark, I guess this would do the job if I script it, but I was hoping to do this on the fly in python using Wand.

Comment: Now it is possible to use it. Extend feature was added in version 0.4.5: https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.6/wand/image.html?highlight=extent#wand.image.BaseImage.extent

Comment: Thanks @mzcarlos, this should be the accepted answer! Minor correction: it is `extent`, not `extend`.

Answer (score 1):

Wand provides transform which can scale your image to the required size while keeping the aspect ratio. You could pad it with a transparent background to make it completely square later.

```
def adjust_ratio(img, w_dst, h_dst):

    img.transform(resize="{0}x{1}".format(w_dst,h_dst))

    w_bor = (w_dst - self.img.width)/2
    h_bor = (h_dst - self.img.height)/2

    if w_bor>0:
        img.border(color=Color('transparent'),width=w_bor,height=0)
    else:
        img.border(color=Color('transparent'),width=0,height=h_bor)
```

Comment: Strangely using this example and transforming by 100x100 the output was 99x100 when I saved. When I did 101x100 the output was 101x100 when I saved (as expected). So just be careful it might give strange results. This was using Wand==0.4.4 .

Comment: To get around this issue create a new image of the right size:
with Image(filename=in_file) as foreground:
    foreground.transform(resize="{0}x{1}".format(width, height))

    with Image(width=width, height=height, background=Color('white')) as out:
        left = (width - foreground.size[0]) / 2
        top = (height - foreground.size[1]) / 2
        out.composite(foreground, left=left, top=top)
        out.save(filename=out_file)

Comment: thanks for your code in comments @Luke. I have revised your code a little.

Answer (score 0):

using [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2676805/luke)'s code from the comment I have achieved the desired result.

With little improvement, if you also want to add padding to the image you can set padding variable.

```
padding = 16
with Image(blob=png_image_blob) as foreground:
    foreground.transform(resize="{0}x{1}".format(width, height))
    with Image(width=width + padding, height=height + padding, background=Color('white')) as out:
        left = int((width - padding - foreground.size[0]) / 2) + padding
        top = int((height - padding - foreground.size[1]) / 2) + padding
        out.composite(foreground, left=left, top=top)
        out.save(filename=destination_file_path)
```